# Haskell function returns prefix

Tags: list, haskell

I am trying to create a function in haskell that takes a predicate and a list as arguments and returns the prefix of the list satisfying the predicate.

the test being:

```
p1tests = [myTakeWhile (/= ' ') "This is practice." == "This"]
```

I have this so far..

```
myTakeWhile :: (a-> Bool ) -> [a] -> [a]
myTakeWhile []    =[]
myTakeWhile (x:xs)=[] : map (x:) (myTakeWhile xs)
```

I receive errors saying except type

Comment: You will need to use the predicate as parameter, and check if the predicate holds for a given element.

Comment: What is your idea in doing this? Can you explain the reasoning behind your `myTakeWhile` a bit? Maybe we can help you get on the right track. Right now your problem is that with `[] : ` in the 3rd line you are more or less implying that `a` itself is a list and this looks more like some kind of *list-concatination* attempt?

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with both the predicate and the elements in the list. The function thus should look like:

```
myTakeWhile :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
myTakeWhile _ [] = []
myTakeWhile p (x:xs)
    | p x = …
    | otherwise = …
```

where the `p x` guard thus covers the case where the predicate is satisfied for the first item of the list, and the `otherwise` is not.

In case the predicate is satisfied, we have to yield `x` and recurse on the tail of the list. I keep filling in `…` as an exercise.